# I can't access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

### Problem:

I can't access `localhost/phpmyadmin/`

before I can access `localhost/phpmyadmin/` but today when I'm trying to access this page I got weird page

also I can access `localhost/xampp/` without any problem

### Question:

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean by weird page?

Comment: You should post more about the error you encounter and maybe check your server logs to see what's happening, post that too (default location: /var/logs/httpd/access_log and /var/logs/httpd/error_log if you're running *nix)

Comment: Also, what OS are you running? Is this windows, max or linux? Is this a desktop or a server?

Comment: i use windows 7 desktop.

Comment: this weird page

LÀFÿ@!JzÍëÌ)i•õÌJzÍëÌˆ¢§PàOÐ ê:i¢Ø+00/C:\ˆ1[@\ªPROGRA~1pï¾î:£[@\ª*_´CFProgram Files@shell32.dll,-21781L1[@aªSkype8ï¾[@\ª[@aª*zÌSkypeL1[@\ªPhone8ï¾[@\ª[@\ª*{ÌPhoneX2ˆ¢O@hT!Skype.exe@ï¾O@hT[@\ª*|ÌSkype.exeU-T+Út¾C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exeLaunch Skype8..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exeC:\Program ........

Comment: this is the weird page 

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/erroruh.png/

Comment: I had this problem too until I stopped MySql and restarted apache, then started MySql up again. For some reason if you start MySQL before Apache, it doesn't work, but as long as Apache starts before MySQL, they work great. I also generally have Tomcat running (for JSPs), but still require Apache to be the first one started. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 138):

what you need to do is to add phpmyadmin to the apache configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the phpmyadmin config to the file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On windows, I think you can just navigate to the apache2 config file and include the phpmyadmin config file as shown above, then restart apache

Comment: Where is the apache2.config file on windows?

Comment: Thanks man it works but i dont know why it doesn't enable that in the first place

Answer (score 23):

A cleaner way is to create the new configuration file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

and write the following in it:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then, soft link the file to the directory `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
```

Comment: anything on nginx?

Answer (score 19):

You should use `localhost:portnumber/phpmyadmin`
Here the `Portnumber` is the number which you set for your web server or if you have not set it until now it is by Default - `80`.

Comment: Where can the setting for the port number be found?

Comment: The default for apache is 80 nad mysql is 3306

Comment: the same error may occur if you are trying to access localhost using the secure https protocol: https://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that both apache webserver and MySQL server are running. I had the same failure because I forgot to start my webserver.

Answer (score 8):

when you run Xampp, check the apache port no. ex: if it is displaying port 80, then type

```
http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/
```

After that it will display automatically

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install phpmyadmin;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Linux Mint :
After installing LAMP along with PhpMyAdmin, I linked both the configuration files of Apache and PhpMyAdmin. It did the trick. Following are the commands.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Answer (score 3):

It generally **occurs** when your **default port for localhost is being used by another application** (like apache tomcat). Easy fix is to **stop the application** and simply go to **localhost/phpmyadmin**.

In my case it *worked* after stopping *apache tomcat*.

Comment: Skype is an offender here. It like to grab port 80, but you can reconfigure it

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's case sensitive.  Have you tried going to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
04/11/12 21:14:22
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: Ok you are using windows? Is your mysql service started?  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1174

Comment: i'm using windows 7. mysql is started

Comment: Try stopping all xampp services and close out of xampp.  Go to the task manager and close all processess that have mysql in the name.  Reopen xampp and then start everything again.  That help any?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, one of your plugins is messing up with the phpmyadmin. Try disabling all plugins to see if that works.

If it does, enable them one by one and check again, to find the problematic one.

Comment: Check if there is gas in the tank first. Just get phpMyAdmin running

Answer (score 1):

Resolving same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, I use code:

```
    sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

it is because since Ubuntu 13, Apache loads configuration files from the /etc/apache2/conf-enabled directory.

[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 1):

You need reload the server.

If you use apache server
`systemctl reload apache2`

If you use nginx server
`systemctl reload nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the output of the image which you linked in one of your comments:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/erroruh.png/

... maybe you accidentally downloaded some form of the website from where you thought you were downloading phpMyAdmin.  The text contains references to "Dropbox" which makes me think that the information displaying is in no way related to phpmyadmin.

Try re-installing and see if that helps...

http://www.phpmyadmin.net

Answer (score 0):

Or it could be that Skype is running on the same port (it does by default).

Disable Skype or configure Skype to use another port

Comment: Yep I agree I tried changing the Skype ports but made no difference. Not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. 
i worked on it and found out ,this is simply because i have mistakenly moved my "phpmyadmin" folder in to a some folder inside Xampp. Go through all the other folders which are inside the main "XAMPP" folder. 
Then if you find the "phpmyadmin" inside another folder other than "xampp" move it back to the main "XAmpp" folder and refresh the page.
 :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to include the phpmyadmin config into apache2 is to create a new config file by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

and write in it:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the Apache server, note down the port number(eg:8081)
Open your browser and type localhost:8081(or apache's port number)

Answer (score 0):

Just change - 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; 
in config.inc.ph. i.e. from existing to localhost if you installed it locally

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the xampp services helped me

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you still have phpMyAdmin maybe you deleted it in your htdocs folder?

Get the latest version: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Unzip then place the phpMyAdmin (rename the folder if it has version numbers) in your htdocs folder.

Make sure Skype is disabled as it will some times run on the same port as your XAMPP install... I'm not sure why but apache installed via xampp on some windows 7 machines ive seen  apache not run if skype is on after 10years of IT work.

So make sure apache is running, mysql is running and hit:

localhost/phpMyAdmin

You should get some kind of install prompt. Step through this you will learn lots along the way. But basically its one config file that needs some settings.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Couldn't access `http://localhost/joomla` neither.
and I did not quite understand the other answers.
The simple solution for me:

1. stop all actions in xampp (I had apache and mysql running. apache on port 80 and 7000something)
2. quit firefox
3. restart the actions (apache and mysql)
4. restart firefox.
5. open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` (or `http://localhost/joomla` - whatever it be)
6. voila!

Now apache runs on port 80 and 443 and mysql on 3306.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to add phpmyadmin to the apache configuration:⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the phpmyadmin config to the file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On ubuntu 18.0.1, I think you can just navigate to the apache2 config file and include the phpmyadmin config file as shown above, then restart apache

http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Come on; even "your" explanations are as identical as the syntax from the accepted answer.