# Can't access localhost/phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I get the "server not found" message in the browser when I try to access localhost/phpmyadmin/ and my websites configured in /etc/hosts and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

My "hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       website1
127.0.0.1       website2

...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any luck if you try http://127.0.0.1 or the IP address of the server directly? Any hints in the Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

Your phpmyadmin configuration might not be included by apache. Open apache.conf using your favorite editor

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart your apache server:

```
sudo service apache restart
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23485413/2071499)

A cleaner way is to create the new configuration file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

and write the following in it:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then, soft link the file to the directory `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
```