# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it-Laravel 9-Windows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i tried to run http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in my browser, but i get this error message "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" im using laravel 9.5.1 and php 8.0.3. And when i run phpMyAdmin i get an error message "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

i've tried to clear config and cache, edited file database.php, .env file and config.inc but it's still didn't work.

this is my database.php file

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'myDatabaseName'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'myPassword'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8', 
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

this is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=myDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME='root'
DB_PASSWORD='myPassword'
```

and this is my config.inc file

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'myPassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

can someone please help me?, thank you

Comment: And when you use said credentials outside of laravel, they work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111455/i-cant-access-http-localhost-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL is running?

Comment: Ensure your WAMP Server (or XAMP) is working. And also check whether MySQL server is running or not. If you not run apache server(or any server you use) this could happen. After run your local server and refresh the page.

Comment: yes mysql is running when i started in xampp. but i just realize when i try to change my password using command promt, i got error massage, it says "can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) check that mtsqld is running and that the socket: 'MySQL' exists!" 
i checked services.msc adn i can't found that mysql is running
 @Stoff

Comment: @MANSOORKOCHY in xampp running, but i'm not sure it's really running

Comment: @CodyBrew my answer is the same as before. have you ever had the same problem? if so, do you have a solution? thank you

Comment: @mimie yes, so many times on local server of office this is due to because server is not working.

Answer (score -1):

- Can you log into your `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`? (it your phpmyadmin in order?)

Your issues looks like your databases credentials aren't correct - it can't access your database

Check whether this helps: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111455/i-cant-access-http-localhost-phpmyadmin`

Comment: I guess a screenshot would help